# If this will... or if this would

Tags: conditionals, would

Can someone tell me which is grammatically sound in this context -- would or will? I've looked through some of the responses to similar questions, but the explanations weren't too clear for a non-native speaker like myself.

I'm not sure if this would make things more convenient for you, but I can meet you directly at the airport...

Or...

I'm not sure if this will make things more convenient for you, but I can meet you directly at the airport...

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Either is acceptable. Using 'would' makes the suggestion a little less definite.